# copying directories using .jar program in java

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-8

i want to copy directories from the the place where my .jar files exist?
here are what i tried.. but i always get /home/user/
how can i copy files from where my .jar program exist?

```
private void copy_dir() {

    //Path sourceParentFolder = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") +        "/Project/");
   //      Path sourceParentFolder = Paths.get(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString());
    Path destinationParentFolder = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

    try {
        Stream<Path> allFilesPathStream = Files.walk(sourceParentFolder);
        Consumer<? super Path> action = new Consumer<Path>() {

            @Override
            public void accept(Path t) {
                try {
                    String destinationPath = t.toString().replaceAll(sourceParentFolder.toString(), destinationParentFolder.toString());
                    Files.copy(t, Paths.get(destinationPath));
                } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
                    //TODO do acc to business needs
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        };
        allFilesPathStream.forEach(action);

    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
        //file already exists and unable to copy
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //permission issue
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: how about some understandable English? and what is the error?

Comment: Why are you getting path for `user.home`? What you want is current directory (`.`).

Comment: user.home is the destination or target..

Comment: i want current directory of my .jar file for example if my .jar is in desktop i want the path of source to: user.home/desktop..

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 Path destinationParentFolder = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

**"user.dir"** gets the absolute path from where your application was initialized.

**"user.home"** gets the user's home directory.